# Is there a way to interact with apps, like opening them, on iOS/Android phones using a Python script?

Tags: android, python, ios, automation

Is it possible, and if so what module, to interact with apps in iOS/Android phones using Python?

Like how PyAutoGUI allows you to click, type, and move your mouse and keys is there a way to do that, but to iOS and Android phones?